# java makefile is making .class files instead of make file

Tags: java, class, makefile

using cygwin to make a make file out of a single java file called memsim.java.
The makefile is called makefile.txt and it's contents is

```
JFLAGS = -g
JC = javac
.SUFFIXES: .java .class
.java.class:
    $(JC) $(JFLAGS) $*.java

CLASSES = \
    Memsim.java

default: classes

classes: $(CLASSES:.java=.class)

clean:
    $(RM) *.class
```

My command is

```
make -f makefile.txt
```

however I am not getting a single "make" file. Instead it's making a file for each class called (file).class (file being the class name).

Using javac from jdk1.7.0_51.

EDIT: All I'm asking for is how to write a file that will make a file called "make" that will compile and run the file Memsim.java. Any information or link as to where I could find an answer would be great.

Comment: What do you mean with `not getting a single "make" file`? If you call `make` it will execute the steps defined in the make file. In your case `makefile.txt`, as you have specified this with the option `-f`.

Comment: Okay I understand that, this is my first java makefile so I guess the tutorial was misleading. Do you know what I have to change in the makefile to get just one make file that will run Memsim.java? Or do you know where I could find out how to? I've googled everywhere

Comment: Why you are not using, for example: maven, for your project? What's the constraint to use `make`?

Comment: Leave aside Java for the moment, do you understand the purpose of make? Then as SubOptimal points out there are similar Java-esque solutions such as Ant, Maven or Gradle that may suit you better.

Comment: This makefile tells make to create a `.class` file for each `.java` file in the `CLASSES` variable. If you want more then that then you need to tell make about those steps also.

Answer (score 0):

A full explanaition of what the commands in your `makefile.txt` mean you can find here http://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~newhall/unixhelp/javamakefiles.html.

If you rename `makefile.txt` to `Makefile` you can compile the `Memsim.java` with `make` (without the need to specify `-f makefile.txt`.

If you add following to your makefile. (keep care about the single TAB instead of spaces in front of `java`)

```
exec:
    java Memsim
```

you can execute the `Memsim` class with `make exec`.

With `make clean` you would remove the `Memsim.class` file.